# Javascript: Array elements into select box as option

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, i want each value inside the array to be displayed in a input select box as an option. This is what i have tried myself:

```
<select>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

for(cars)
{
    document.write("<option>"cars"</option>");
}
</script>
</select>
```

Comment: - `<script>` should not be child of `<select>`
- `for-loop` has some different syntax than what you have tried
- Search for `appendChild` or `innerHTML` than `document.write`

Comment: Have you done any research? There's a million websites out there that can help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it with for loop easily

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
{
    var diVContent = '<option>'+cars[i]+'</option>';
    document.write(diVContent);
}
</script>
```

Comment: what does i<cars.length; do just curious the script is working btw thanks, will accept in a bit

Comment: it is a lentgth of your array, to get each element , you need to loop over all elements

Answer (score 2):

with this javascript it should be like this

```
<select id="MySelectBox">
</select>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

for (i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
        option+= "<option value='"+cars[i]+"'>"+cars[i]+"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("MySelectBox").html= option;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code and try:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

 var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
 var select_c = '<select>';
 for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
 {
     select_c += '<option>'+cars[i]+'</option>';

 }
 select_c += '</select>';
 document.write(select_c);
</script>
```

You can see the fiddle here: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/czLy3sgy/)